# PHP - Creating an object that can scale to new columns attributes?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've been working on a small and simple project to learn PHP. The goal is to make a simple library catalog that allows one to add books to the database (SQL Server 2017), edit the books currently in the table, and delete books from the table.

I've made a book class and a SQL connector class so far and one of the goals was to make the book class easily scalable when the user wants to add new columns.

I do not know how to exactly do this and I feel like most of my class is too "hard-coded" to work with the columns I have already defined. As a result, I would like some help in fixing my classes so that it is easily more scalable when the user wants to add in new columns.

Besides that, any general fixes or small improvements to my code would be also appreciated.

Here are the codes for my current Book and SQL Connector class:

Book Class:

```
<?php
/**
Book Class
Book.php
 */

spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) {
    include $class_name . 'php';
    echo "$class_name has been included";
});


class Book
{
    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $author;
    protected $genre;
    protected $quantity;

    protected $database;
    protected $tablename;

    /*
     * Constructor Function to create a book object with specified
     * values for each field and then inserts the book into the SQL Server
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->title = $data['title'];
        $this->author = $data['author'];
        $this->genre = $data['genre'];
        $this->quantity = $data['quantity'];

        $this->database = new \SQL_Connector\SQL_Connector();
        $this->tablename = $this->database->getTableName();

        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (Title,Author,Genre,Quantity) 
                            VALUES ('$this->title','$this->author','$this->genre',$this->quantity)";

        $this->database->updateDB($sql_insert);

    }

    /*
     * Function that takes new data and separates it accordingly.
     * The data is used to construct an update statement and then
     * passed to a different function that will update the database
    */
    public static function updateBook($new_data){

        $database = new \SQL_Connector\SQL_Connector();

        $table = $database->getTableName();

        $id = $new_data['id'];
        $newTitle = $new_data['title'];
        $newAuthor = $new_data['author'];
        $newGenre = $new_data['genre'];
        $newQuantity = (int)$new_data['quantity'];


        $sql_update = "UPDATE $table SET Title='$newTitle', Author='$newAuthor',
                        Genre='$newGenre', Quantity=$newQuantity WHERE ID = $id";


        $result = $database->query($sql_update);
    }


    /*
     * Function to find a specific book based on ID.
     * Takes an ID as a parameter and executes a query to search for
     * a book that matches the ID in the database. Returns an array with
     * all the associated values for each column of the found book.
     * Function is mainly used by the edit page to display the values
     * of a specific book based on which one was selected to be edited
     * */
    public static function findBook($id): array{

        $db_connect = new \SQL_Connector\SQL_Connector();
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $db_connect->getTableName() . " WHERE ID = $id";

        $query = $db_connect->query($sql_query);
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $row;

    }

    /*
     * Function to check if user inputs are valid.
     * No nulls are accepted for each column and
     * each column has a specific maximum length allowed
     * The return value is an array containing all the
     * error messages for each invalid input
     */
    public static function validation($data):array{
        $errors = array();

        if(empty($data['title'])){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Title cannot be empty. \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }
        else if (strlen($data['title']) > 30){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Title is too long \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }

        if(empty($data['author'])){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Author cannot be empty \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }
        else if (strlen($data['author']) > 20){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Author is too long \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }

        if(empty($data['genre'])){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Genre cannot be empty \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }
        else if (strlen($data['genre']) > 10){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Genre is too long \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }

        if(empty($data['quantity'])){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Quantity cannot be empty \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }
        else if (!is_numeric(($data['quantity']))){
            $errMsg = "Invalid input: Quantity must be an integer \n";
            $errors[] = $errMsg;
        }

        return $errors;
    }

    /*
     * Function to fill out any empty inputs with old inputs
     * for when users are trying to update an entry and leave
     * an input blank. The user inputs are checked to see if
     * any are blank. Any blank inputs are replaced by the old
     * data, otherwise, use the user input. The return value is
     * an array containing the data to be used in the update statement
     */
    public static function defaultUpdateInfo($userInput, $oldData): array{

        $data = array();

        $data['id'] = $oldData['ID'];

        if(($userInput['title'] == '') || ($userInput['title'] == null)){
            $data['title'] = $oldData['Title'];
        }
        else{
            $data['title'] = $userInput['title'];
        }

        if(($userInput['author'] == '') || ($userInput['author'] == null)){
            $data['author'] = $oldData['Author'];
        }
        else{
            $data['author'] = $userInput['author'];
        }

        if(($userInput['genre'] == '') || ($userInput['genre'] == null)){
            $data['genre'] = $oldData['Genre'];
        }
        else{
            $data['genre'] = $oldData['genre]'];
        }

        if((!is_numeric($userInput['quantity'])) || ($userInput['quantity'] == null)){
            $data['quantity'] = (int)$oldData['Quantity'];
        }
        else{
            $data['quantity'] = (int)$userInput['quantity'];
        }

        return $data;

    }
}
```

SQL Connector Class:

```
namespace SQL_Connector;


class SQL_Connector
{

protected static $config;
protected static $connectionInfo;

protected $database;

    /*
     * Constructor to create instance of object.
     * Function calls the db_connect function to
     * establish a connection to the database
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_connect();
        return $this->database;
    }

    /*
     * Function to establish a connection to the database
     * based on information from the config.ini file
     * The return value is a PDO object with a connection
     * to the database
     */
     public function db_connect(): \PDO{

        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
        $username = $config['username'];
        $dbname = $config['dbname'];
        $password = $config['password'];
        $server = $config['server'];

        try{
            $this->database = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$dbname",$username,$password);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die (dprint_r("Connection error. Connection to database not established\n"));
        }
        $this->database->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->database;

    }

    /*
     * Function to perform a specific query.
     * The parameter is an SQL statement and the function
     * takes it, prepares it, and executes it.
     * The return value is the PDOStatement from the execution
     * of the query
     */
    public function query($sql_query): \PDOStatement{
        $database = $this->db_connect();
        $database->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query = $database->prepare($sql_query);
        $query->execute();

        return $query;

    }

    /*
     * Function to update the database. The parameter is the
     * SQL statement containing the necessary data to update
     * a specific entry successfully. Return value is the PDOStatement
     *
     * Function is most likely unneeded and the regular query function
     * can be used instead.
     */
//    public function updateDB($sql_data){
//        $database = $this->db_connect();
//        $database->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//
//        $update = $database->prepare($sql_data);
//        $update->execute();
//
//        return $update;
//    }

    /*
     * Function to fetch all rows in a table.
     * The function finds all entries in the table
     * and fetches all of them and the associated data
     * for each. The return value is an array containing
     * all the rows from the table. This function is mainly
     * used by the index page to display all books in the table
     */
    public function getAll():array{
        $database = $this->db_connect();
        $table = $this->getTableName();
        $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;

        $query = $database->prepare($sql_query);
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }

    /*
     * Function to get table name. Table name may
     * be changed in the config file so this function
     * can get the name of the table and use it for each
     * SQL statement accordingly. The function is mainly used
     * to allow changing the name of the table without
     * disrupting the rest of the functions. Unsure if this is needed
     */
    public function getTableName(): string {
        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

        return $config['tablename'];
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help and I most appreciate it.

Comment: Design your table structure so that you use an attributes and bookattributes tables rather than adding new columns to the books table

Comment: @MarkBaker Besides that, there's nothing code-wise I could do to achieve something similar? I'll start looking into restructuring the table to achieve the scalability I want. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to store the data somewhere, and adding arbitrary columns to a database table isn't a good approach... an alternative would be to have a json column on that table to store the additional data

Comment: @MarkBaker Alright I'll look into your suggestion then. Just to make sure I am understanding correctly, I'd have to make two tables, one which stores the books and one which stores the attributes of the book? I'm still a relatively new to SQL and creating databases so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: You're better making 3 tables, 1 for the books, one for the names of new attributes, and a third for the book id, attribute id and value... that allows the same attribute to be applied to different books, but with different values.... e.g. if you have book 1 (Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone) and book 2 (Percy Jackson Lightning thief) in your books table, and somebody decides to create a new attribute 1 (print type) in the attributes table, the they could add entries to the bookattributes table for book 1, attribute 1, value "Large Print", and for book 2, attribute 1, value "normal print"

Comment: @MarkBaker Great idea! Thank you for the suggestion and help

Comment: It sounds like @MarkBaker should be posting his suggestion as the answer and the OP should be marking it off as the correct one.